# FireBreath: unknown CMake command "find_firebreath_X11_deps"

Tags: cmake, firebreath

After successfully installing firebreath (git clone, git update, python) I wanted to run

```
prep2010.cmd projects build
```

But I always get an error:

```
Generating plugin configuration files in G:/firebreath/build/projects/red/gen
CMake Error at src/PluginAuto/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_firebreath_x11_deps): 
Unknown CMake command "find_firebreath_x11_deps".
```

What could be the reason for that?

This only happens with the 1.7 branch. 1.6 works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug.  It's fixed now; pull the latest.

Sorry about that, we're in the middle of prepping for the 1.7 release and that bug slipped by us.